# How to track the location of a window belonging to another app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

When screen sharing a specific window on macOS with Zoom or Skype/Teams, they draw a red or green highlight border around that window (which belongs to a different application) to indicate it is being shared. The border is following the target window in real time, with resizing, z-order changes etc.

See example:

[image]

What macOS APIs and techniques might be used to achieve this effect?

Comment: There was an almost-identical topic a few days ago.  It was dismissed, I think.  Isn't it you who wrote it?

Comment: Accessibility API is not the only method to do so, but as you need users consent to avoid being banned into sandboxing thats the way to go. And be sure even Zoom and Skype are using the API. Well maybe WebRTC involved.. but still to share a screen from outside a wkwebview they need users consent at least while installing.

Comment: Sure, they have screen recording permission but not accessibility permission. Also, accessibility observers only fire *after* the window was moved but neither of those apps show any noticeable delay in updating.

Comment: If you are just talking about drawing the green box (and not actually capturing the contents), you can find the location of windows using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` and related API, which is available to Sandboxed apps. Drawing a border would be done by creating your own transparent window overlaid on top of the original window, and draw a green box into it. I would elaborate further if we can get this question reopened.

Comment: @ElTomato - I've edited the question to make it more specific. Will you consider a reooen vote?

Comment: Count me out.  It sounds to me that 'Tell me which API or class I should use' is the same as 'Tell me the library I should use, ' which is off the topic here.

Comment: @NickMoore `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` does give me the window bounds and I can adjust them using frequent polling. However it does not tell me whether other windows are on top, partially/fully obstructing it. For that I tried `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenAboveWindow  | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, ...)` and checking for intersecting rects but that is too slow to do with polling.

Comment: @Hypherion kCGWindowLayer ought to help with this as well as the relativeToWindow parameter. Calculating intersecting rects ought to be very fast if you filter smartly and take time to get the code right. You'd be surprised how fast numerical operations are on modern processors when there's no API calls or IO involved. And the CGWindowList API is speedy. The SonOfGrab sample code is great platform to try out this stuff. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SonOfGrab/

Comment: @Hypherion - ooh and we are open. I've shifted the content of my contents to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the location of windows using [`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo) and related API, which is available to Sandboxed apps.

This is a very fast and efficient API, fast enough to be polled. The [SonOfGrab](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code is great platform to try out this stuff.

You can also install a global event tap using [`+[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1535472-addglobalmonitorforeventsmatchin?language=objc) (available in sandbox) to track mouse down, drag and mouse up events and then you can respond immediately whenever the user starts or releases a drag. This way your response will be snappy.

(Drawing a border would be done by creating your own transparent window, slightly larger than, and at the same window layer as, the window you are tracking. And then simply draw a pretty green box into it. I'm not exactly sure about setting the z-order. The details of this part would be best as a separate question.)

Comment: I will give this a try. Previously when I tried getting the window information and intersecting rects, my app was basically blocked due to the frequent polling. I think this is because I was doing it on the main queue so will use a new approach, thanks.